# Download a file from an implicit SSL/TLS FTP using R

Tags: r, ftp

I did have a look on google and SO but couldn't find an answer to my question. As part of data security we're sent daily data files on a sharefile website. The sharefile site mentions the files can be downloaded via FTP and they also included the below information.

Security:   Implicit SSL/TLS (Port 990) - Required

I've been able to download files off sites before but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shan